# Swift 3 - How to remove all Subviews from Superview as well as Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiview

I currently have a double for-loop that creates an X by Y grid of UIView CGRect squares. The loop also adds each UIView/Square of the grid to a 2D array allowing me to access each Cell of the grid and alter color/positioning by the index values of the loop.

The loop seems to work fine and displays the Cells/Squares perfectly, however after a while I want to remove all of the squares and also empty the array (but not entirely delete) to make room for a new next grid (which may be of a different size). I created a function to remove all the views from the superview.

This is how I am creating each "Cell" of the grid and placing each into the 2D array:

```
let xStart = Int(size.width/2/2) - ((gridSizeX * gridScale)/2)
let yStart = Int(size.height/2/2) - ((gridSizeY * gridScale)/2)

let cell : UIView!
cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xStart + (xPos * gridScale), y:yStart + (yPos * gridScale), width:gridScale, height:gridScale))

cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.02).cgColor
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0)

cell.tag = 100

self.view?.addSubview(cell)

gridArray[xPos][yPos] = cell
```

The 2D array is being created on application load like so:

```
gridArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil, count: gridSizeY), count: gridSizeX)
```

I have tried to search for a solution to remove the UIViews from the superview however all answers from other Questions don't seem to work for me. I have tried to add `cell.tag = 100` to each UIView and then remove all UIViews with the Tag Value of 100 like:

```
for subview in (self.view?.subviews)! {
    if (subview.tag == 100) {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

However no luck. I have also tried to use this method:

```
self.view?.subviews.forEach({
    $0.removeConstraints($0.constraints)
    $0.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

The main differences I notice in my code compared to other peoples answers is that I have "?" and "!" at places in the code. I researched about what they mean and understood most of it however I still do not know how to fix my code because if it, and feel as though that is the issue. All I know is that the attempts to remove the UIViews from the superview does not work, and without the "?" and "!"s the code doesn't run at all.

Comment: why don't you create a _view_ which contains all views as subviews you intend to remove...? then when you need to remove these views you just need to remove their superview only (or just hide it optionally) – that would seem to me an easier way to deal with such situation and it would not ruin the constraints either – if I got you correctly.

Comment: That does like a better solution. Could you explain how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

How about to create tag for each cell you are using for example:

```
    //Init value for for the tag.
    var n = 0

    func prepareCell() -> UIView {
             let xStart = Int(size.width/2/2) - ((gridSizeX * gridScale)/2)
             let yStart = Int(size.height/2/2) - ((gridSizeY * gridScale)/2)

         let cell : UIView!
         cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xStart + (xPos * gridScale), y:yStart + (yPos * gridScale), width:gridScale, height:gridScale))

         cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
         cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.02).cgColor
         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0)

        cell.tag = n

        //Each cell should have new value
        n += 1

        return cell
}
```

And now remove required views.

```
func removeViews() {
    for z in 0...n {
        if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(z) {
           viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        else {
           print("tag not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Example that is working in the playground:

```
var n = 0

let mainView = UIView()

func createView() -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    view.tag = n
    n += 1
    return view
}

for i in 0...16 {
    mainView.addSubview(createView())
}

func removeViews() {
    for z in 0...n {
        if let viewWithTag = mainView.viewWithTag(z) {
            viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
             print("removed")
        }
        else {
            print("tag not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am attempting you solution now, however when I get to `let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(z)` it is telling me to add a question mark after "view" to become `let viewWithTag = self.view?.viewWithTag(z)` and when I run it, it seems to print get into both conditions of the IF and only loops twice, not "n" number of loops, but still see squares on the screen that haven't been removed.

Comment: @Terminal I create simple example in the playground so you can see how it is working in the simple code.

Comment: That's great! I should be able to take it apart to see where mine is breaking and fix it. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Terminal no problem was glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You might be overlooking a much, much simpler way to do this...

You have built a 2D Array containing references to the "cells" as you populated your view. So, just use that Array to remove them.

```
// when you're ready to remove them
for subArray in gridArray {
    for cell in subArray {
        cell.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

// clear out the Array
gridArray = Array<Array<UIView>>()
```